# Help in understanding Bochner's theorem

Tags: soft-question, definition

This relates to the Bochner's theorem stated in the link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem

My question is related to the unique probability measure μ on G. I want to express the term $dμ=g1(x)dx$ (In terms of another function say $g1$) My question what kind of $g1$ is applicable? Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are asking if $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Haar measure?  What if the function $f$ is identically 1?  Then $\mu$ is the Dirac mass at $0$.  Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: May I ask why did you specify Haar measure? I am trying to understand application area of Bochner's theorem, specifically in Engineering area. So, I am thinking is there several way to construct the measure mu/ dmu or there is no such ideas exist?

Comment: $dx$ often denotes Haar measure.  In the special case of the reals, this is just the Lebesgue measure.  I still don't understand what you are asking here.  What do you mean by $\mu/d\mu$?

Comment: I mean dmu I do not see mu/dmu sorry. \the term mu and dmu is defined in the wikipedia link.. my question is how to construct them. If this question is meaningless, would you let me know why\/ Even that will help my understanding. The term dx is not meant anything specific here; It is whatver that can b applicable to the problem

Answer (score 3):

Here is the finite dimensional version of Bochner's Theorem.  Maybe this will help you.  If $f = (f_n)_{0 \le n \le N-1}$ is a positove definite sequence, then there exists another sequence $g = (g_n)_{0 \le n \le N-1}$ such that $f$ is the discrete Fourier transform of $g$, and $g_n > 0$.  Positive definite means
$$ \sum_{i,j=0}^{N-1} f_{(i-j)\bmod N} x_i x_j > 0 $$
whenever $x = (x_n)_{0 \le n \le N-1}$ isn't identically zero.  Equivalently the circulant matrix https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix built from $f$ is a positive definite matrix.

In the finite dimensional case, it is easy to construct $g$ - just take the inverse discrete Fourier transform.  But in the general situation, you don't know *a priori* that the inverse Fourier transform exists.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. I will think of this answer more.  My motivation here is to estimate a function say k which is element of L1. May I ask if it is possible? Generally for L2 fourier is nice as we get L2 to L2. I am interested to estimate element of L1.

Comment: The Fourier transform maps functions from $L^1$ to $L^\infty$.  But it won't map to all elements of $L^\infty$, only those that are the difference of two positive definite functions.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thank you. It may be a very important point. can it be proved?

Comment: Yes.  The converse to Bochner's Theorem, that the Fourier transform of a positive measure (and hence the Fourier transform of a positive $L^1$ function) is positive semi-definite, is straightforward.  Then just look at the positive and negative parts of the $L^1$ function you are looking at.

Comment: Thank you. So, I can assume that Bochner theorem can b used to estimate element of L1? This is my main question I want to ask?

Comment: How do you want to estimate an element of $L^1$?

Comment: I assumed that function g1 in my question is an element of L1 therefore if we estimate some given spectrum values with some g1 using Bochner theorem, we would get element of L1. I would really appreciate your view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25999/discussion-between-stephen-montgomery-smith-and-creator).